# How to get the GlowFilter color in as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a code like the one bellow, that adds glow to the text.

> var glow:GlowFilter = new
>   GlowFilter(); glow.color = 0x000000;
>   glow.alpha = 1; glow.blurX = 5;
>   glow.blurY = 5; glow.quality =
>   BitmapFilterQuality.MEDIUM;
>
> text_ti.filters = [glow];

The problem is that, I need to find a way, to later be able to get the glow color! I cant's find a way to retrieve the glow color....

Could someone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, actually - very similar to the way you get it.

```
// Get your color
var mycolor:uint = glow.color;
trace(mycolor);
```

Check out the [ASDocs for GlowFilter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filters/GlowFilter.html). Reading about get and set functions (also known as mutators and accessors, might help you in a web search) might help you as well. Good luck.

Edit: Your question wasn't clear. See [this link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#filters) for getting and setting a filter array from a displayobject.

Comment: It did't work. I add inputfields dynamically, and they have glow. So, when I click the inputfield, I need to get its glow color...

Comment: Hello. I tryed to understand, but not success!

Comment: you probably have a scoping issue move var glow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter(); outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

trace(text_ti.filters[0].color);

should do it. This assumes that the GlowFilter is the only filter applied. The "filters[0]" indicates the first item in the array of filters. This will give you the decimal equivalent of the hex color you've assigned.